# Avoid terminal characters from previous terminal commands

Tags: gnome-terminal, bashrc

Well, I think you know pretty well what I'm talking about; if not, check [this video](https://youtu.be/itzrm_3wHIg). Basically, when you press your up array to obtain the previous command, often the characters are left on the terminal. Is there any way to circumvent the problem?

---

EDIT: This problem doesn't happen with `gdb` only, but also with a normal terminal. This should be the interesting lines in `.bashrc`

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

---

EDIT2: Ok, I'll try to explain it with an example. Suppose you have this terminal history (pretty simplified for the sake of simplicity):

```
user:host$>cd foo/bar
user:host$>sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
user:host$>clear
user:host$>
```

Then, if you press your up arrow key 3 times, you are expecting something like

```
user:host$>cd foo/bar
```

but you are obtaining instead

```
user:host $>sudo apcd foo/bar
```

This is the least funny scenario you can end up with, I must admit; sometimes there are a so complex mosaico on the screen that you want to crash anything. I don't know which is the cause, I think I probably bad formatted something in the `.bashrc` file, but still I don't know what.

However, changing the previous `.bashrc` lines to something like this

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='\[\033[1;31m\]\u:\[\033[1;37m\]\W\\$>\[\033[0;32m\]'
    PS2='\[\033[1;37m\]>\[\033[0;32m\]'
else
    PS1='\u:\W\\$'
    PS2='>'
fi
```

the problem partially disappears: it's not happening anymore in normal shell, but if I launch `gdb` for example it happens most of the time. Can it be related to the special characters?

---

EDIT3
Here are the relevant lines in `~/.gdbinit` file; you can find the whole file [here](https://github.com/gdbinit/Gdbinit/blob/master/gdbinit). Maybe the final `\]` string is missing, isn't it?

```
 if $USECOLOR == 1
    # BLACK
    if $arg0 == 0
        echo \033[30m
     // a lot of other if-else conditions
```

Comment: What is your prompt set to, and how? I'm not familiar with gdb's way of setting the prompt, but it uses readline, and readline expects escape sequences (e.g. switching to red) to be enclosed within `\[` and `\]`, or `\x01` and `\x02` (not sure which), omitting these is a typical problem with color bash prompts that leads to pretty much the same behavior as seen in this video.

Comment: @egmont see the edit

Comment: There are way too many things happening in the video and we can't see the keys you press. Could you please describe with words one particular buggy behavior (keypresses, actual vs. expected behavior)? I'm not sure what your problem exactly is.

Comment: @egmont Well, it's not too easy to explain, but I thought the problem was common because I've seen it in so many videos. Btw, read the new edit.

Comment: In bash's prompt definition, _exactly_ those characters (and only those) that do not advance the cursor upon being printed (that is, escape sequences) need to be enclosed inside `\[` and `\]`. I can't see where it's buggy in your original prompt definition, perhaps you pasted the wrong lines. What does `set | grep ^PS1` say?

Comment: For gdb, you have to locate where gdb's red prompt is defined and check whether it complies to the previous requirement. Instead of literal `\[` and `\]`, the enclosing characters might be the  `0x01` and `0x02` bytes there, I'm not sure.

Comment: @egmont you're right, I posted the original file coming with a fresh install. Indeed, I changed this file some days ago and the problem is not present anymore, but it continues to appear in `gdb`. For what I'm seeing and basing on your comment, I think that there's a missing `\[` at the ond of the colors. See EDIT3 for further clarifications.

Comment: Not just the closing `\[` but also the opening `\]` is missing, presumably also where changing to red.

Comment: @egmont damn, I thought brackets were used just the opposite :) So, `\]\033[30m\[` is the way to go? I've also found lines tagged as `\033[31mgdb$ \033[0m\]\[`. Should I surround them with the opening and closing tag? I'm a little bit confused. If you can make a full answer, I'll be very glad to mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I have indeed swapped the opening and closing ones in my previous comment. It should obviously be `\[\033[30m\]`. Your gdb prompt should be `\[\033[31m\]gdb$ \[\033[0m\]`.

Comment: @egmont unfortunately, it doesn't solve the problem. Indeed, even the color settings are now wrong (check the [video](https://youtu.be/sLD6bPLJVvg) and, if necessary, [the original file](https://github.com/gdbinit/Gdbinit/blob/master/gdbinit) )

Comment: There's no sign of `\[` and `\]` whatsoever in the file you linked. I've probably missed to double-escape these chars, e.g. try `\\[`, `\\]` or something along these lines. You should try `\001` and `\002` too, probably readline requires these.

Comment: @egmont while the first solution, with the double escape characters, didn't work, adding a lot of redundant characters to the prompt, the second one improved the situation a lot. The only problem now is that, when there is a newline in the command, it reverts to the old bad behavior ([video](https://youtu.be/kSjs7uH-Ncc); with inline commands, however, the behavior is good (well, until now :D)

Comment: I'm adding this as an answer then. I don't know how to handle multiline prompts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `bash`'s primary prompt (`$PS1`) all non-printable characters (e.g. escape sequences that change the color) have to be enclosed between literal `\[` and `\]`.

Similarly, for all other readline-based apps, such as `gdb`, non-printable characters in the prompt need to be enclosed between a `0x01` and a `0x02` byte. You can refer to these in `.gdbinit` as `\001` and `\002`.